# How Can I Change Tableview Array with Segment Control

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I Have a one table view and i have two array. My arrays name AllItems and SpecialItems. I Use segment control. I wantto if segment value is 0 tableview load AllItems Array, When change segment value and value is = 1 than mytableview reload tada but SpecialItems array. Can u help me please. Thanks.

Comment: Show what you have tried... Otherwise they might vote to close your question.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem with table tag.

```
- (IBAction)segmentControlChanged:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {

if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
    mytable.tag = 1;
}
else 
{
    mytable.tag = 0;
}

[mytable reloadData];
}




- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{ 

   if(tableView.tag==1)
{

    return [specialItems count];
}

else

return [allItems count];


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create two data source classes that implement all the `UITableViewDataSource` methods: one for `AllItems` and one for `SpecialItems`. To switch between the two, connect a `valueChanged` action. In the method that is called, set the data source and reload the table view.

```
- (void)valueChange:(UISegmentedControl *)sender
{
    if (/* condition for all items */) {
        self.tableView.dataSource = self.allItemsDataSource;
    } else {
        self.tableView.dataSource = self.specialItemsDataSource;
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would personally create an array which the data is loaded from. Put this in your implementation:

```
NSArray * _tableData
```

Then in your viewDidLoad just allocate this for the array which we want it to start on.

```
_tableData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:allItems];
```

This initially loads the data we will always see as the segment control starts on index 0. We have to set the initial data somewhere so the tableView loads with some data in it.

Then set the number of rows and the cellForRowAtIndex to pick up from the _tableData array

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return _tableData.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView_ cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView_ dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:bCell];

    // Here we use the specific array as we would normally

    return cell;
}
```

This step means the tableView will load with the array. Even if the array is empty the view will still load as the number of cells will be zero.

Now in our value changed function we can reset the array as we need to:

```
- (IBAction)segmentControlChanged:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {

    if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
        _tableData = allItems;
    }
    else {
        _tableData = specialItems;
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

You just need to make sure the segment control changed is linked up in the XIB file (or programatically) and that you reload the table after choosing the array.

This kind of thing is actually really easy to do. I would definitely recommend working it through step by step if you're having trouble. Make sure each step is working before applying the next:

1. Get the tableView loading with both sets of data individually
2. Confirm that the segment control is calling the change function when clicked

Then that should do it